# Does app update through firebase notification count as app_remove event in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

Through firebase notification, when a user taps on the notification(or the app is in the foreground), the updated apk on the server gets downloaded(the link to the apk file on the server is send through notification data) and then the apk is installed and the app gets updated.

The question is does this count as an app_remove firebase event?
If any doubts about the question, please leave a comment.

Thanks for your time.